# jQuery nested .each() getting outside of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, each

I'm using the code below to save the order of multiple sortable lists via Ajax call, and for some reason it runs the call multiple times per click. I get 4 to 8 alerts if there are two lists in the #resedit div.

I can't understand why the ajax call or alert would be made more than once... the only thing happening in the .each functions is building a variable, and they're fully closed out before anything else occurs.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
var listorder = '';
    $('#resedit').children().each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none' && $(this).attr('id') != '') {
        listorder = listorder + $(this).attr('id') + ', ';
                $(this).children().each(function(indexchildren) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none' && $(this).attr('id') != '') {
                        listorder = listorder + $(this).attr('id') + ', ';
                        placeholder = indexchildren;
                        }
                    });
        }
        });
    var data = {
        action : 'save_res',
        security : '<?php echo $saveres_nonce; ?>',
        resorder : listorder,
        resumeslug : $('#res-dash-select').val(),
        }
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
        return;
        });
    });
```

Comment: There's an extra `});` at the end which leads me to believe that there's more code that this is within.  Is there something else that this is wrapped in or is that just unneeded `})`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax call is within the (outer) `children().each()` call. So it will be called once for every immediate child of `#resedit` div.

And I guess the `#resedit` div has between 4 and 8 children.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm sure it's not. `The children().each()` call is closed right before `var data =`     To add to the mystery, it appears as though the number of iterations is directly related to the number of times the #resedit div has been updated via .html() with the ajax responses from other functions. First time twice, then three, then four, etc...

Comment: You have `children().each()` twice. The inner one closes before `var data = ` as you say. But the outer one closes at the very end of the pasted code.